# PowerShell Core: Register-PSRepository not working with UNC Path

Tags: powershell, repository, local

I am using Powershell 7.3.9.

I am trying to set up a local repository to share my powershell stuff. It's a smb fileshare. And i fail to get it right.

Command:

```
Register-PSRepository -Name Test -SourceLocation '\\10.0.0.1\PS' -PublishLocation '\\10.0.0.1\PS' -InstallationPolicy Trusted -Credential $Credential
```

Result:

```
Register-PSRepository: Cannot find the path '\\10.0.0.1\PS' because it does not exist.
```

The provided credentials are definetly correct.
I can register the same repository the exact same way on another PC just fine.

Now, when i map the share to a drive letter and use that as the location, it also appears to work on this PC:

```
Register-PSRepository -Name Test -SourceLocation 'P:' -PublishLocation 'P:' -InstallationPolicy Trusted
```

But now, when i try to find or install any module from that repository, it fails to find it.

Command:

```
Find-Module -Name TOML -Repository Test
```

Result:

```
Find-Package: No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'TOML'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.
```

Command:

```
Find-Module -Repository Test
```

Result:

```
...
WARNING: The file extension 'P:\TOML.0.1.0.nupkg' is not valid. The required file extension is '.nupkg'.
...
```

While on the other pc, where i registered the repository using UNC path, it finds all the modules just fine.

So the files have the correct extension, but it appears PowerShellGet has a problem with repositories on mapped network drives...

Even the confusion is confused. How can i troubleshoot this on how to register the repository the proper way? I am all out of ideas :(

Comment: What version of PowerShellGet are you using? Try updating it: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet